# marker show info window on end drag

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want the info window of my marker to appear when the marker has been dragged to a point.
I want the address to appear in it.
My LogCat gives me the correct address so that works fine, but the infowindow does not show

here's my code

```
private void placeMarker() {
    getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(getMyLocation())
            .draggable(true)
            .snippet("")
            .title(""));
    getMap().setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            latLng = marker.getPosition();
            marker.setSnippet("Loading address...");
            marker.showInfoWindow();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1).get(0);
                String addressString = address.getAddressLine(0);
                addressString += "\n"+address.getAddressLine(1);
                marker.setSnippet(addressString);
                marker.showInfoWindow();

                Log.d("get address pinpoint", "drag end: " + addressString+ " shown:" + marker.isVisible());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need non-empty title to show default info window.

Change `marker.setSnippet(addressString);` to `marker.setTitle(addressString);`

As a side note: **never** call blocking code on the UI thread. `geoCoder.getFromLocation` is internally calling webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marker.showInfoWindow();